# Connecting your own header file in C

Tags: c, makefile

Project structure: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cGDz.png)

When starting the makefile, I get an error: src/main.c:1:10: fatal error:

```
lib/hello.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <lib/hello.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:10: main.o] Error 1
```

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -Werror
CPPFLAGS = -I lib

all: hello

hello: main.o libhello.a
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) main.o hello.o -o hello

main.o: src/main.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $^

libhello.a: hello.o
    ar rcs $@ $^

hello.o: lib/hello.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -rf *.o hello
```

main.c:

```
#include <lib/hello.h>

int main(void)
{
    printHello();

    return 0;
}
```

hello.h

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
        
void printHello(void);
```

hello.c

```
#include <lib/hello.h>

void printHello(void)
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

How to properly connect your header file using <>? Using relative paths through "" is not allowed.

Comment: "Using relative paths through "" is not allowed." So what is `#include <lib/hello.h>` then?

Comment: *Using relative paths through "" is not allowed.* Ehh? `#include "lib/hello.h"` should be fine?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Comment: You can use three consecutive back-ticks before and after your monospaced text to visualize the tree structure instead of using a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-I .` instead of `-I lib` in your makefile. The `lib` is already written in the source files, i.e. `#include <lib/hello.h>`.

```
$ tree
.
├── Makefile
├── lib
│   ├── hello.c
│   └── hello.h
└── src
    └── main.c

2 directories, 4 files
$ make
cc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I . -o main.o src/main.c
cc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I . -o hello.o lib/hello.c
ar rcs libhello.a hello.o
cc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I . main.o hello.o -o hello
$ tree
.
├── Makefile
├── hello
├── hello.o
├── lib
│   ├── hello.c
│   └── hello.h
├── libhello.a
├── main.o
└── src
    └── main.c

2 directories, 8 files
$ ./hello
Hello World!
$
```

Comment: Nothing has changed.

Comment: @12iq Please try again with `.`. See updated answer.